# Add search bar to Custom Database Table in Wordpress Dashboard

Tags: database, search, dashboard, wp-list-table

I have built a custom table within the WordPress database. From there I have put together a plugin which creates a dashboard page allowing you to view the various rows within the database by extending the WP_List_Table function. What I need to do now is add a search bar functionality. I have been able to add the search bar and loads the results page, however with no results given.

I need to be able to search a specific column within the custom database titled 'Card' and display the results.

Here is what I have so far. Any direction and case specific samples would be gratefully appreciated.

```
 <?php

 if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
 }

 class Members_List extends WP_List_Table {

    /** Class constructor */
    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct( [
            'singular' => __( 'Member', 'red' ), //singular name of the listed records
            'plural'   => __( 'Members', 'red' ), //plural name of the listed records
            'ajax'     => false //does this table support ajax?
        ] );

    }


    /**
     * Retrieve members data from the database
     *
     * @param int $per_page
     * @param int $page_number
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function get_members( $per_page = 5, $page_number = 1 ) {

        global $wpdb;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM  my_members";

        if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['orderby'] ) ) {
            $sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['orderby'] );
            $sql .= ! empty( $_REQUEST['order'] ) ? ' ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['order'] ) : ' ASC';
        }

        $sql .= " LIMIT $per_page";
        $sql .= ' OFFSET ' . ( $page_number - 1 ) * $per_page;

        if( ! empty( $_REQUEST['s'] ) ){
        $search = esc_sql( $_REQUEST['s'] );
        $sql .= " WHERE card LIKE '%{$search}%'";
    }

        $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, 'ARRAY_A' );

        return $result;
    }


    /**
     * Delete a members record.
     *
     * @param int $id member ID
     */
    public static function delete_member( $id ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $wpdb->delete(
            "my_members",
            [ 'ID' => $id ],
            [ '%d' ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns the count of records in the database.
     *
     * @return null|string
     */
    public static function record_count() {
        global $wpdb;

        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_members";

        return $wpdb->get_var( $sql );
      }


    /** Text displayed when no member data is available */
    public function no_items() {
        _e( 'The Members Database is currently empty.', 'red' );
    }


/**
 * Render a column when no column specific method exist.
 *
 * @param array $item
 * @param string $column_name
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
    switch ( $column_name ) {
        case 'Member_ID':
        case 'Card':
        case 'First':
        case 'Last':
        case 'Class':
            return $item[ $column_name ];
        default:
            return print_r( $item, true ); //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
    }
}

/**
 * Render the bulk edit checkbox
 *
 * @param array $item
 *
 * @return string
 */
function column_cb( $item ) {
    return sprintf(
        '<input type="checkbox" name="bulk-delete[]" value="%s" />', $item['ID']
    );
}


/**
 * Method for name column
 *
 * @param array $item an array of DB data
 *
 * @return string
 */
function column_name( $item ) {

    $delete_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'red_delete_member' );

    $title = '<strong>' . $item['name'] . '</strong>';

    $actions = [
        'delete' => sprintf( '<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&customer=%s&_wpnonce=%s">Delete</a>', esc_attr( $_REQUEST['page'] ), 'delete', absint( $item['ID'] ), $delete_nonce )
    ];

    return $title . $this->row_actions( $actions );
}


/**
 *  Associative array of columns
 *
 * @return array
 */
function get_columns() {
    $columns = [
        'cb'      => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'Member_ID' => __( 'Member ID', 'red' ),
        'Card'    => __( 'Card', 'red' ),
        'First' => __( 'First Name', 'red' ),
        'Last'    => __( 'Last Name', 'red' )
    ];

    return $columns;
}


/**
 * Columns to make sortable.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function get_sortable_columns() {
    $sortable_columns = array(
        'Member_ID' => array( 'Member_ID', true ),
        'Card' => array ( 'Card', true)
    );

    return $sortable_columns;
}

/**
 * Returns an associative array containing the bulk action
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function get_bulk_actions() {
    $actions = [
        'bulk-delete' => 'Delete'
    ];

    return $actions;
}


/**
 * Handles data query and filter, sorting, and pagination.
 */
public function prepare_items() {

    $this->_column_headers = $this->get_column_info();

    /** Process bulk action */
    $this->process_bulk_action();

    $per_page     = $this->get_items_per_page( 'members_per_page', 7 );
    $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
    $total_items  = self::record_count();

    $this->set_pagination_args( [
        'total_items' => $total_items, //WE have to calculate the total number of items
        'per_page'    => $per_page //WE have to determine how many items to show on a page
    ] );

    $this->items = self::get_members( $per_page, $current_page );
}

public function process_bulk_action() {

    //Detect when a bulk action is being triggered...
    if ( 'delete' === $this->current_action() ) {

        // In our file that handles the request, verify the nonce.
        $nonce = esc_attr( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] );

        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'red_delete_member' ) ) {
            die( '' );
        }
        else {
            self::delete_member( absint( $_GET['member'] ) );

                    // esc_url_raw() is used to prevent converting ampersand in url to "#038;"
                    // add_query_arg() return the current url
                    wp_redirect( esc_url_raw(add_query_arg()) );
            exit;
        }

    }

    // If the delete bulk action is triggered
    if ( ( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'bulk-delete' )
         || ( isset( $_POST['action2'] ) && $_POST['action2'] == 'bulk-delete' )
    ) {

        $delete_ids = esc_sql( $_POST['bulk-delete'] );

        // loop over the array of record IDs and delete them
        foreach ( $delete_ids as $id ) {
            self::delete_member( $id );

        }

        // esc_url_raw() is used to prevent converting ampersand in url to "#038;"
            // add_query_arg() return the current url
            wp_redirect( esc_url_raw(add_query_arg()) );
        exit;
    }
    }

 }

 class Member_Management_Plugin {

    // class instance
    static $instance;

    // member WP_List_Table object
    public $members_obj;

    // class constructor
    public function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'set-screen-option', [ __CLASS__, 'set_screen' ], 10, 3 );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'plugin_menu' ] );
}


public static function set_screen( $status, $option, $value ) {
    return $value;
}

public function plugin_menu() {

    $hook = add_menu_page(
        'Manage Members',
        'Manage Members',
        'manage_options',
        'wp_list_table_class',
        [ $this, 'plugin_settings_page' ]
    );

    add_action( "load-$hook", [ $this, 'screen_option' ] );

}


/**
 * Plugin page
 */
public function plugin_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <style>
      table {display: block;overflow-x: scroll;max-width:98%;}
      th {min-width:100px;font-size:10px;}
    </style>
        <h2>IBEW 353 Member Management Portal</h2>
                <div id="post-body-content">
                    <div class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
                        <form method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="page" value="wp_list_table_class" />
                            <?php
                            $this->members_obj->prepare_items();
                            $this->members_obj->search_box('Search', 'search');
                            $this->members_obj->display(); ?>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <br class="clear">
<?php
}

/**
 * Screen options
 */
public function screen_option() {

    $option = 'per_page';
    $args   = [
        'label'   => 'Members',
        'default' => 7,
        'option'  => 'members_per_page'
    ];

    add_screen_option( $option, $args );

    $this->members_obj = new Members_List();
}


/** Singleton instance */
public static function get_instance() {
    if ( ! isset( self::$instance ) ) {
        self::$instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$instance;
    }

 }


 add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function () {
    Member_Management_Plugin::get_instance();
 } );
```

UPDATE:
As you see I have the search bar visible now but am not able to correctly fetch the results. What would I add in order to search the Card column and display the results and how would I add it.

How would I add the search form in order to load the page with the new results from the search bar? Any code samples would be gratefully appreciated.

I have tried the suggestions provided and reviewed the reference link however the links tutorial appears to ahve broken code within the content and as such was hesitant I am already trying to  debug one solution.

With hands in the air I am relying on the community for further insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it in where you're doing your custom query called by prepare items:

```
public static function get_members( $per_page = 5, $page_number = 1 ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM  my_members';

    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['orderby'] ) ) {
        $sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['orderby'] );
        $sql .= ! empty( $_REQUEST['order'] ) ? ' ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['order'] ) : ' ASC';
    }

    $sql .= " LIMIT $per_page";
    $sql .= ' OFFSET ' . ( $page_number - 1 ) * $per_page;

    if( ! empty( $_REQUEST['s'] ) ){
        $search = esc_sql( $_REQUEST['s'] );
        $sql .= " WHERE card LIKE '%{$search}%'";
    }

    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, 'ARRAY_A' );

    return $result;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but that should be what you're looking for.  You should also look at using `$wpdb` and included functions like `$wpdb->prepare` to formulate your SQL queries using WordPress built in handling, escaping, etc

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

**UPDATE:**
You also need to update anywhere you make custom database queries to handle including the WHERE statement, including counts, etc.

I recommend that you review this example, and rewrite your entire list table class based on this tutorial, which uses a custom database table data, and has the search handling integrated as well:
https://webkul.com/blog/create-admin-tables-using-wp_list_table-class/

Comment: thank you for the insight @sMyles I have tested out the suggestion you made and am now seeing the new search result page come up however it is responding with "The Members Database is currently empty." though I can verify a member is in that column. Am I missing something?

Comment: I updated my response, that's because your class needs to be updated anywhere you're making a query, for counts, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. After I added it to the counts, I also had to move the if statement right below global $sql = 'SELECT * FROM  my_members'; I have also cleaned up the variables and such as you noted for a cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this:

$sql .= " LIMIT $per_page";
$sql .= ' OFFSET ' . ( $page_number - 1 ) * $per_page;

under this:

if( ! empty( $_REQUEST['s'] ) ){
$search = esc_sql( $_REQUEST['s'] );
$sql .= " WHERE card LIKE '%{$search}%'";